# Amazon cognito facebook integration on Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I use amazon cognito to keep user datas,

Facebook integration was completed to user login. I used facebook sdk 4.0 for connecting.
I tried to complete login process with datas that I obtain from facebook but I encountered little and frustrating problem.

I referred to [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/devguide/identity/external-providers/facebook/#using-facebook) resource for connecting amazon cognito but I encountered problem below.

[image]

because AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() returns AccessToken object doesn't return String object.

I have been researching on internet about one hour but I haven't solved my problem so far.

Comment: Have u tried AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().toString();?

Comment: Yes I have tried. It didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry for the issues in the Amazon Cognito documentation. The correct value according to the [Facebook documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/AccessToken/) is:

```
AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getToken()
```

Comment: Yes it is correct answer.
I founded that after frustrating and boring one hour.
Thank you.